# spark examples not building

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, dependencies

I downloaded the example Spark code from https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/.  I did the mvn package call.  It ran for a long time.

However, when I run "mvn install" in the spark-examples_2.1.1 folder, I get the errors below.  Any help on how to get this project building and debugging?

```
 [INFO] Building Spark Project Examples 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT 
 [INFO]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[WARNING] The POM for
 org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
 dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
 org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
 dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
 org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT is
 missing, no dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
 org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT is
 missing, no dependency information available [INFO]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 0.864 s [INFO] Finished at:
 2017-02-15T18:02:07-05:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/303M [INFO]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-examples_2.11: Could
 not resolve dependencies for project
 org.apache.spark:spark-examples_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT: The following
 artifacts could not be resolved:
 org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT,
 org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT,
 org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT,
 org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT:
 Could not find artifact
 org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
 Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
 enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
 the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1]
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got passed this error message.   Upgrading my version of Maven to the newest version got me past this and onto other build issues.